# get 'From' or sender address from apple's Mail

Tags: email, scripting, applescript

I'm new to scripting and am trying to write a simple script for mail. I need sender address from that or we can say From address. But I'm not getting anything from it. My script is as below.

```
tell application "Mail"
    try
        set theSelectedMessage to selection
        set msgCount to count of theSelectedMessage
        if (msgCount = 1) then
            set theMsg to item 1 of theSelectedMessage
            #also tried this
            #set theSender to extract name from sender of theMsg
            set theSender to (sender of theMsg)
            display dialog "name:" & theSender
        end if
    end try
end tell
```

Dialog is coming but no detail of sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohhhh
I forgot to enable my mail account cause of that I was facing problem.
Mail > Preferences > Accounts > Account Information > Enable this account

Answer (score 1):

Basically `extract name from` is the right way

```
tell application "Mail"
    set selectedMessages to selection
    if selectedMessages = {} then return

    repeat with aMessage in selectedMessages
        set senderName to extract name from sender of aMessage
        set senderAddress to extract address from sender of aMessage
        display dialog "    name: " & senderName & return & "address: " & senderAddress
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: This code is supposed to work. I tested it successfully.